# Can't open file selected by user in GetOpenFileName()

Tags: c, winapi

What is causing my program to fail while loading files? I'm posting the two function involved.

I'm using the `libcomdlg32.a` library to get the path using a user-friendly interface.

```c
void display_file(char *path)
{
    FILE *file;
    char filecontent[1000];
    printf("path %s\n", path);
    if ((file = fopen("path", "r")) == NULL)
  printf("cant open this file.\n");
  else{
    while(!feof(file)){
        fscanf(file,"%s",filecontent);
       }
    }
    printf("%s",filecontent);
    SetWindowText(hdisplay,filecontent);
}


void open_file(HWND hWnd)
{
    OPENFILENAME ofn;//dichiariamo la structure
    char Filename[100];

    ZeroMemory(&ofn,sizeof(OPENFILENAME));//inizializziamo a 0 la struct, gli arogmenti sono la structure e la grandezza
    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);//settiamo la grandezza della structure
    ofn.hwndOwner = hWnd;//l'handler sappiamo già cos'è
    ofn.lpstrFile = Filename;//avrò il path del file selezionato quindi qua dovremmo avere una stringa
    ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';//non abbiamo default file, meglio settarlo in questo modo così da non avere problemi in lettura ecc
    ofn.nMaxFile = 100; //la maggiore grandezza in byte del path
    ofn.lpstrFilter = "Text Files\0*.txt\0" ;//filtra la visulazzazione dei file equivale a vedere solo file txt ecc
    ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
    GetOpenFileName(&ofn);//ha bisogno di essere linkata una libreria specifica per compilarlo
    display_file(ofn.lpstrFile);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code:

In `display_file()`, you are ignoring the input `path` parameter, you are passing the string literal `"path"` to `fopen()` instead of the `path` parameter.  Also, you are leaking the `FILE` object, you need to call `fclose()` when done using the file. And you need to initialize the 1st character of `filecontent` to `'\0'`, in case `fopen()` or `fscanf()` fail, otherwise you won't be passing a properly terminated string to `printf()` or `SetWindowText()`.

In `open_file()`, you need to check the return value of `GetOpenFileName()` for success before calling `display_file()`.

Try this instead:

```c
void display_file(const char *path)
{
    FILE *file;
    char filecontent[1000];
    filecontent[0] = '\0';
    printf("path %s\n", path);
    if ((file = fopen(path, "r")) == NULL){
        printf("cant open this file.\n");
    }
    else{
        while (!feof(file)){
            fscanf(file, "%999s", filecontent);
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
    printf("%s", filecontent);
    SetWindowText(hdisplay, filecontent);
}

void open_file(HWND hWnd)
{
    OPENFILENAME ofn;//dichiariamo la structure
    char Filename[100];

    ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(OPENFILENAME));//inizializziamo a 0 la struct, gli arogmenti sono la structure e la grandezza

    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);//settiamo la grandezza della structure
    ofn.hwndOwner = hWnd;//l'handler sappiamo già cos'è
    ofn.lpstrFile = Filename;//avrò il path del file selezionato quindi qua dovremmo avere una stringa
    ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';//non abbiamo default file, meglio settarlo in questo modo così da non avere problemi in lettura ecc
    ofn.nMaxFile = 100; //la maggiore grandezza in byte del path
    ofn.lpstrFilter = "Text Files\0*.txt\0" ;//filtra la visulazzazione dei file equivale a vedere solo file txt ecc
    ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
    if (GetOpenFileName(&ofn)){ //ha bisogno di essere linkata una libreria specifica per compilarlo
        display_file(ofn.lpstrFile);
    }
}
```

Also, on a side note: each call to `fscanf()` is going to *replace* the contents of `filecontent` with the next word read from the file.  It is not going to *append* each word to `filecontent`.  So, when your `while` loop is finished reading, `filecontent` will contain only the *last* word read.  Is that what you really want?  If not, then consider reading the file differently.  For instance, you could query the file's size with `_stat()`, then `malloc()` a `char[]` of that size, and then `fread()` the whole file into the `char[]`.